# FizzBuzz using JavaScript Switch

Tags: javascript

Can't seem to point out something obvious. This solution doesn't work. Please help?

> **FizzBuzz question**: Print numbers from 1 to 100. Print Fizz instead of numbers divisible by 3. Print Buzz instead of numbers divisible by 5. Print FizzBuzz instead of numbers divisible by both 3 and 5.

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
 
 switch (i) {

      case (i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0):
        console.log('FizzBuzz'); 
        break;

      case (i%3 === 0):
        console.log('Fizz');
        break;

      case (i%5 === 0):
        console.log('Buzz');
        break;

      default:
        console.log(i);

 }
    }
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Errors? Wrong output? Something else?

Comment: Why are you using switch? Is that something that task requests or is it just your choice?

Comment: The closest you can get to your code whilst still using a `switch` block is [this](http://jsbin.com/yexowopiku/1/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you are switching on the value of variable `i`. Then you are comparing that with expressions like `i % 3 === 0`, so the comparison becomes `i === (i % 3 === 0)`.

Instead, you can switch on `true`, so any expression evaluating to true will be switched into.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  switch (true) {
    case (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0):
      console.log('FizzBuzz');
      break;

    case (i % 3 === 0):
      console.log('Fizz');
      break;

    case (i % 5 === 0):
      console.log('Buzz');
      break;

    default:
      console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

A switch enters the branch if the case matches the value you are switching for, therefore:

```
  switch (i) {
    case (i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0):
```

Will enter the first case if:

```
 i === (i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0)
```

E.g. for `15` it will be:

```
 15 === true // -> false
```

so it wont enter the branch. Therefore instead of switching for `i` you have to switch for `true`:

```
  switch(true) {
```

Answer (score -3):

Did you try not to break the switch, because when it matches it won't print the other stuff it is supposed to? Maybe?